# Display images with proper dimensions before loading using glide and recyclerview

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview, feed, android-glide

How do I display images in a facebook like feed? So far I've been using match_parent for width and wrap_content or fixed height. This works well but I need to show proper blank space for image feeds while it's getting lazy loaded. Like how do I set the dimensions properly for the image before loading it from the internet.

I think about getting the aspect ratio or the image dimensions itself via the api. Is it the only correct way or is there some other better way to achieve it using glide or any image loading library?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using glide, you can set a place holder image or drawable with the dimensions you need while the real image is being downloaded.

```
Glide  
.with(context)
.load(UsageExampleListViewAdapter.eatFoodyImages[0])
.placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) // can also be a drawable
.into(imageViewPlaceholder);
```

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark my response as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to know how facebook sets image size in the news feed. Like some large images are scaled to center and some images are displayed as it is. How to do like that?